# spring cloud dataflow compatibilty with base cloud foundry versions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am reading this release announcement for Spring Cloud dataflow. 
https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/22/spring-cloud-data-flow-for-cloud-foundry-1-1-1-maintenance-release-available

I am wondering if we need a minimum version of cloud foundry for successfully running spring cloud data applications.. Given that this stream of work is actually targeted for cloud based environments, i think they should also mention the minimum base Cloud Foundry versions that can support them.

Does this require an inter-process communication that's being made available in latest cloud foundry versions 
https://www.cloudfoundry.org/meet-new-container-networking-stack-cloud-foundry/
https://content.pivotal.io/blog/building-spring-microservices-with-cloud-foundrys-new-container-networking-stack

I do see the mention of PCF version compatibility for Spring Cloud Tasks
http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_version_compatibility

But i haven't been able to find the Base cloud foundry version that supports the features of Spring Cloud Data Flow in general or per feature compatibility breakdown with Cloud foundry versions. We are running IBM Bluemix in our company and are upgrading to the cf version that supports Deigo architecture (vs the current DEA) - don't know the exact version of CF will that be.

If we know the Spring Cloud Data flow feature compatibility with specific Cloud Foundry versions we can decide our adoption strategy accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to PCF vs. OSS CF [compatibility matrix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/#pcf-vs-oss-cf-compatibility) from the project site.

This matrix captures the baseline OSS CF release required to run SCDF on the particular PCF versions. You could further dive into respective PCF release-notes to double check other OSS components (*eg., CAPI*) for more granular compatibility measurements.

Tasks in SCDF, in particular, is GA'd with PCF 1.9; so if you're planning to use it, you'd have to be at least on OSS CF 246 release.